# Vectorize the midpoint rule for integration

Tags: python, numpy

I need some help with this problem. 
The midpoint rule for approximating an integral can be expressed as:

```
                         h * summation of f(a -(0.5 * h) + i*h)
```

where h = (b - a)/2

Write a function midpointint(f,a,b,n) to compute the midpoint rule using the numpy sum function.

Make sure your range is from 1 to n inclusive. You could use a range and convert it to an array.

for midpoint(np.sin,0,np.pi,10) the function should return 2.0082

Here is what I have so far

```
import numpy as np

def midpointint(f,a,b,n):
h = (b - a) / (float(n))
for i in np.array(range(1,n+1)):
    value = h * np.sum((f(a - (0.5*h) + (i*h))))
return value

print(midpointint(np.sin,0,np.pi,10))
```

My code is not printing out the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue with the posted code was that we needed accumulation into output : `value += ..` after initializing it as zero at the start.

You can vectorize by using a range array for the iterator, like so -

```
I = np.arange(1,n+1)
out = (h*np.sin(a - (0.5*h) + (I*h))).sum()
```

Sample run -

```
In [78]: I = np.arange(1,n+1)

In [79]: (h*np.sin(a - (0.5*h) + (I*h))).sum()
Out[79]: 2.0082484079079745
```